# Azure DevOps - is it possible to add a service connection in the free tier?

Tags: azure, connection, devops, free

Seems I'm missing that option from my settings. Is it because I'm using the free tier?

Don't see the option "Service Connections" following the steps below:

> Sign in to your organization (
> [https://dev.azure.com/{yourorganization}](https://dev.azure.com/%7Byourorganization%7D) ) and select your project.
>
> ```
> Select Project settings > Service connections.
> Select + New service connection, select the type of service connection that you need, and then select Next.
> Choose an authentication method, and then select Next.
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

> **Note** that:  It is possible to add a service connection in the free tier in Azure DevOps.

I have an Azure DevOps **Free Tier** account:

[image]

I logged in to the **[Azure DevOps Portal](https://dev.azure.com/)**, created a project like below:

[image]

*Select Project settings > Service connections->Select New service connection -> select the type of service connection -> Next.*

[image]

I created a New Service connection like below:

[image]

***The service connection got successfully created like below:***

[image]

***The issue usually occurs***, if the user doesn't have access, check this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#user-permissions).

- Check whether Parallelism grant is approved for your account (Private or Public).
- Check whether the Azure DevOps is connected to your Subscription.

**References:**

[Service connections in Azure Pipelines - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#user-permissions)

[A teammate cannot see or reuse service connections.. GitHub by StingyJack](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/6482)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to create the service connections on my free tier account.